# Is there an easy way to see all Azure AD tenants that have signed into your multi-tenant application?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have configured an app to allow multi-tenant sign in to my application by going to app registrations and set Who can use this application or access this API?
to "Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant)".

This works well however now I want to see all the tenants that have successfully signed into my application. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following to list all tenants:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/Tenants/List?tabs=HTTP

Then you can use either Postman or Insomnia. Here is a link to get [Azure Active Directory token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/aad/app-aad-token).

It will list all tenants.

Alternatively, you can use Powershell cmdlet: `Get-AzTenant`

Comment: This will tell you how many tenants you have access to. What OP is looking for is a list of tenants their multi-tenant application has been installed in.